# webpack : is there a good hook / custom function to dump out resolved configuration?

Tags: configuration, webpack

I'm somewhat of a newbie with webpack and have been experimenting with easier ways to adjust/merge webpack configurations.

The following code, added to **webpack/lib/webpack.js** has been pretty helpful:

this is the standard webpack.js:

```
function webpack(options, callback) {
    var compiler;
    if(Array.isArray(options)) {
        compiler = new MultiCompiler(options.map(function(options) {
            return webpack(options);
        }));
    } else if(typeof options === "object") {
        new WebpackOptionsDefaulter().process(options);

        compiler = new Compiler();
        compiler.options = options;
        compiler.options = new WebpackOptionsApply().process(options, compiler);
        new NodeEnvironmentPlugin().apply(compiler);
        compiler.applyPlugins("environment");
        compiler.applyPlugins("after-environment");
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid argument: options");
    }
    if(callback) {
        if(typeof callback !== "function") throw new Error("Invalid argument: callback");
        if(options.watch === true || (Array.isArray(options) &&
                options.some(function(o) {
                    return o.watch;
                }))) {
            var watchOptions = (!Array.isArray(options) ? options : options[0]).watchOptions || {};
            // TODO remove this in next major version
            var watchDelay = (!Array.isArray(options) ? options : options[0]).watchDelay;
            if(watchDelay) {
                console.warn("options.watchDelay is deprecated: Use 'options.watchOptions.aggregateTimeout' instead");
                watchOptions.aggregateTimeout = watchDelay;
            }
            return compiler.watch(watchOptions, callback);
        }
        compiler.run(callback);
    }
```

this is my code:

```
    //customization start
    fs = require('fs');
    var fnp_dump = 'webpack.dump.json';

    fs.writeFile(fnp_dump, JSON.stringify(options, null, 2), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("dumping dump.webpack.js.final.json from webpack.js to: " + fnp_dump);
    }); 
    //customization end


    return compiler;
}
```

The basic idea is that it dumps out the final json/js options object **after** webpack has finished sorting out the usual *webpack.base.js + webpack.development.js*.  Since it's, at that point, just a fully-resolved javascript object, it doesn't really matter how the config.js files were written by individual developers.

Now you can **diff** options sent to webpack (this is an example of tranforming webpack 1 to webpack 2 configurations:

`diff 003/webpack.dump.json 004/webpack.dump.json`

```
<         "loader": "style!css!postcss-loader!sass"
---
>         "use": [
>           {
>             "loader": "style-loader"
>           },
>           {
>             "loader": "postcss-loader"
>           },
>           {
>             "loader": "sass-loader"
>           }
>         ]
```

However, I am customizing **webpack.js** directly and need to re-apply my patch after each `npm update webpack`.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `webpack.config.js` is a function, you can call it on your own to resolve to an object.

If you have several configs (you mentioned `webpack.base.js` and `webpack.development.js`) you can use [Webpack Merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) to just combine your options to a single object, and then write it to the file system.

I would recommend you to have an own script in `package.json` to do this job, which you can then always call after your webpack job:

```
...,
"scripts": {
    "dump-options": "scriptThatMergesConfigsAndWritesToFS.js",
    "webpack-job": "webpack ... && npm run dump-options",
    ...
},
...
```

### UPDATE

After some more research I realized, that the resolved options object is stored in the compiler object. The compiler object is passed to Plugins, and therefore you can [easily write a Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/) that writes the config to a file, [as I did here](https://gist.github.com/wtho/fb924ab487e9c2b99076555b92f31092) (not tested).

I also realized, that the Plugins cannot be stringified, as they are functions, so be aware of losing the Plugin configuration information.

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty good idea.  My webpack config is not a function right now, but guess I could change that.  Might be a while before I test it however, working on something different now.  As far as Webpack Merge goes, I am aware of it, but I'd rather know/control exactly what the configs are up to and that's with this dump and diff approach does for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own plugin (and now notice that **wtho** wrote one too).  It worked for me - note you need to have the bit of code that handles circular references:

```
// WebPackCompilationObserver.js

function WebPackCompilationObserver(options) {
  WebPackCompilationObserver.options = options || {};
}

WebPackCompilationObserver.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {

  compiler.plugin("emit", function(compilation, callback) {

    var fs = require('fs');
    var fnp_dump = WebPackCompilationObserver.options.dump_filename;

    if (! fnp_dump) {
      fnp_dump = "./dump.webpack.options.json";
      console.log("please specify dump_filename path in the WebPackCompilationObserver.options, otherwise using default:" % fnp_dump);
    }

    if (fnp_dump){
        console.log("dumping compilation.options to: " + fnp_dump);
        var cache = [];
        fs.writeFile(fnp_dump, JSON.stringify(compilation.options, function(key, value) {
              if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
                  if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                      // Circular reference found, discard key
                      return;
                  }
                  // Store value in our collection
                  cache.push(value);
              }
              return value;
          }, 2),
          function(err) {
              if (err) {
                  return console.log(err);
              }
          });
        cache = null;
    }
    callback();
  });
};

module.exports = WebPackCompilationObserver;
```

To use it:

**webpack.config.development.js**:
    ....
    var WebPackCompilationObserver = require("./WebPackCompilationObserver");

```
....

config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
....
,new WebPackCompilationObserver({dump_filename: '../dumpithere.json'})
])
```